# Web API OData without defining a class for results

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, odata

I would like to create an OData endpoint using ASP.NET Web API that can return results for which I do not know the type until run time.  The purpose is to allow the user to create ad hoc queries against a SQL Server database.

For example, I could generate a SQL view at run time based on their query selections and then display the results back in a grid.  Or I could skip the SQL view and generate a LINQ query dynamically.

I would like to use an EntitySetController to support server-side paging and whatnot, but what should I use for TEntity, given that I do not know what fields it should hold at compile time?

Comment: This will not work. An OData URL like /customers must represent a single collection. What you could do is scan your database and dynamically generate classes that represent the possible entities and then maybe generate EntitySetControllers.